# Does the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} K_0(nx)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, bessel-functions

Fix $x>0$ and consider the function
$$
F(x) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} K_{0}(n x)
$$
where $K_0$ is the $0^{\mathrm{th}}$-order modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Does this sum diverge? I know that $K_{0}(z) = \frac{e^{-z}}{\sqrt{z}}$ for $z \to \infty$, so it seems feasible that it converges to something. I don't know how to show this.

Comment: If this asymptotic formula for $K_0(z)$ is true then you can apply the limit comparison test (I am not really familiar with properties of Bessel functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that for $x>0$ and $n\ge1$,

\begin{align}0<K_0(nx)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-nx\cosh(t)}{\rm~d}t\\&<\int_0^\infty e^{-nx(1+t^2/2)}{\rm~d}t\\&=e^{-nx}\int_0^\infty e^{-nxt^2/2}{\rm~d}t\\&\le e^{-nx}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty e^{-xt^2/2}{\rm~d}t}_{{\rm constant~w.r.t.~}n}\end{align}

which is weaker than the inequality you provided.

It remains then to be proven that

$$0<\sum_{n=1}^\infty K_0(nx)<\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}\int_0^\infty e^{-xt^2/2}{\rm~d}t$$

converges, which is simply a function of $x$ times a geometric series.

---

Note the integral converges for any $x>0$. Left up to the reader. $\ddot\smile$